# What does sync.mutex lock?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, locking, mutex

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

type B struct {
    balance int32
    m *sync.RWMutex
}

var (
    a = 100

    b = &B {
        balance:1000,
        m:&sync.RWMutex{},
    }
)

func main()  {
    b.m.Lock()
    a--
    b.balance--
    b.m.Unlock()
}
```

Like the example upon, what does `b.m` lock?  just b?  b and a?  or the lock does not lock objects but the critical section?

If `b.m` locks the critical section instead of `b.*` then what's the point of put a `sync.Mutex` into a struct?

Comment: `Mutex.Lock` locks the mutex, nothing else. It is up to you to use it correctly to synchronize access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Mutex` guarantees only that if something has locked it, it cannot be locked again by something else until the lock is first released. It is up to you to use it correctly, by ensuring that you obtain a lock before you try to access whatever you want protected by the lock, as you've done in your example `main`.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is short and clear.